# How to replace a value after "=" on using bash script?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, sed

Hello I'm new to Bash scripting, in my program there is a text file called test.txt, it contains the line lie this,

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:postgresql://testdbdoamin.com
```

IN here I need to change the value of

```
[jdbc.url= jdbc:postgresql://testdbdoamin.com] to  
[jdbc.url= jdbc:postgresql://preproddomain.com]
```

using bash script any idea how to do this ? Any help would be greatly appreciated.